# "Missing parentheses in call to 'print'." in apyori

Tags: python, anaconda, apriori

Trying to install apriori and use that algorithm for a school project. Stuck because it keeps giving me this error:

```
Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(freqSet-conseq,'-->',conseq,'conf:',conf)?
```

I have tried running it in a different notebook, I tried running `from apyori import apriori`. Nothing seems to work.

```
import apriori
```

I did `pip install` in anaconda, and when I run `import apriori` I get that error which is above.

Comment: It may be a Python 2 library that you're trying to use with Python 3.  If so, either look for a Python 3 version or switch to Python 2.

Comment: it sounds, you are working with `python3.x` and you installed `apriori` which `python2.7` compatible.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/efficient-apriori/ is it the same you are looking for?

Comment: That's right. It was old in python2. Efficient apriori fixed it! Thanks!